# How to get the time for which screen is ON

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application which will warn the user if the screen is been ON for a long time.
The basic idea behind the app is to warn the user about the long exposure of eyes to the screen light.
I basically want the time for which the screen light is turned ON.
If it reaches a certain limit then, the user will be notified to turn the screen OFF for some time.

> How to get the time for which screen is turned ON?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the documentation...

```
public static final String ACTION_SCREEN_OFF

Added in API level 1
Broadcast Action: Sent after the screen turns off.

This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

Constant Value: "android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"
```

---

```
public static final String ACTION_SCREEN_ON
Added in API level 1
Broadcast Action: Sent after the screen turns on.

This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

Constant Value: "android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"
```

When the screen is turned on keep track of the current time and then set an alarm for a certain period of time and then warn the user.

Comment: oh yes .. This is perfect .

Answer (score 0):

You can track user with device time and can save same in SharedPreferences for further checks ..

Get system time like ..

```
// using Calendar class
Calendar ci = Calendar.getInstance();

String CiDateTime = "" + ci.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + 
    (ci.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" +
    ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " +
    ci.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" +
    ci.get(Calendar.MINUTE) +  ":" +
    ci.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

There's lot of answer for this available on stack and Google as well ..

good luck!

Comment: this just shows how to get a string representation of the current time, this has nothing to do with how long the device screen has been on